# equivalent objects in SQL Server Cursors

Tags: sql, cursor

I'm wondering is their any other way to loop over tables, instead of using **Cursors**. Can you suggest to manipulate over tables row by row, we have to use cursors only.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? What problem are you trying to solve. Most of the time a proper set based approach using a single statement is much more efficient than using a cursor in the first place.

Comment: I'm trying to read rows one by one which are linked to another 3 more tables, and if some columns are matching the set criterion i'm updating in linked tables. In this case I'm creating three temp tables.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server you have the `sp_MSforeachtable` to execute an sql command on each table.

For example, adding an `isActive` column to all of the tables in the DB:

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable 
@command1='ALTER TABLE ? ADD COLUMN isActive BOOLEAN;',
```

It is an undocumented procedure, you can read more about it [here](http://raresql.com/tag/sp_msforeachtable/)

Comment: Just to keep in mind that `sp_MSforeachtable` is undocumented internal API and can change in future. You should not rely on it.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but actual requirement is to iterate over rows which have inner joins to other tables and requires to update certain columns based on certain criterion.